# Kiel oni tradukas la anglan esprimon "data usage" al Esperanto?

Tags: single-word-requests, translation

Kiel oni tradukas la anglan esprimon "data usage" al Esperanto? Unue mi pensis pri uzi la vorton "datumo", sed tio signifas "(komputile traktebla) informo" kaj "data usage" temas pri "uzata kvanto de bitokoj".

Temas ekzemple pri ĉiumonata poŝtelefona uzado de interreto, kiel ĉi tie:

[image: Ekzempla bildo]

Answer (score 2):

Mi ne certas, ĉu mi bone komprenas *data usage* - ĉu ĝi rilatas nur al la konsumado de telefon-interretaj datumoj, aŭ ĉu ĝi estas uzata ankaŭ pli ĝenerale?

En la lasta okazo, eble taŭgas *datuma uzo* (kp. *memoruzado* por "memory usage" en Komputeko), en la unua okazo oni povus ĝin plispecifigi al *retdatuma uzo*.

Comment: Ĝi estas la grafo de kilobajtoj de komputilaj datumoj (ne voĉon) kiuj estis transdonitaj en ĉi facturación periodo.

Answer (score 1):

Mi sugestas ***uziteco*** aŭ *uzeco* (aŭ, por mallongigi, simple *uzo*).

La adjektivo povas esti *datuma* aŭ *bita* aŭ *kvota* ("quota").

Comment: Mi ne povas trovi la radikon *uzit/* en PIV. Kio estas tio?

Comment: _uz-it-ec-o_ - la eco estis uzita. Miaponie tiu vorto ne taŭgas, same _uzeco_, ĉar temas pri kvanto, ne kvalito. Mi ne komprenus ĝin.

Comment: Stulta mi! Kompreneble tio estas *uz-* + *-it-*. Dankon! Ankaŭ mi pensas, ke tio vorto ne estas taŭga.

Comment: Oni ja povas uzi *-eco* por aludi gradon de eco (kaj ĉi tie *uzito* ne eblas). Ekz. *la instruiteco, kiun mi havas en ĝi, tute ne povas esti nomata alta* (el *Marta*). Kontraŭe, *uzo* ĉefe signifas unuopan agon, ne kvanton.